# eConnect 10 Errors Numbers - how can I check what they mean?

Tags: c#, exception, dynamics-gp, econnect

I'm implementing `Microsoft Dynamics eConnect 10` in a custom project, and while testing the `EntryPoint` method that's supposed to write to the `ERP`, it throws an exception when some data are missing or not entered correctly.

The exception is descriptive and well explained, but my question is how to find the exhaustive list of error numbers that `eConnect 10` might throw?

Example of an exception ** (ERROR NUMBER 3442)**

```
Sql procedure error codes returned:
Error Number = 3442  Stored Procedure taSopLineIvcInsert  Error Description = Invalid Currency, a Functional currency must be set up
Node Identifier Parameters: taSopLineIvcInsert                                 
SOPNUMBE = RTN-VAN000000002
SOPTYPE = 4
Related Error Code Parameters for Node : taSopLineIvcInsert                                 
CURNCYID = Z-UD$
```

P.S.: Nothing found in the `eConnect 10` default Documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain a list of error codes by:

```
SELECT * FROM DYNAMICS..taErrorCode
```